# Can a library (.so) dynamically load another library built with a different compiler

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries, libraries

**Summary:**

I am having troubles with one library dynamically loading another another and I'm wondering if difference in the compilers is the root cause.

**Problem Details:**

My application links into libgbm.so which dynamically loads libpvrGBMWSEGL.so and then requests the gbm_backend function.

```
#libgbm.so

module = dlopen("/usr/lib/libpvrGBMWSEGL.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL)
dlsym(module, entrypoint)
```

When I try to use the symbol provided, it throws a segmentation fault.

**Analysis:**

libpvrGBMWSEGL.so is provided as a proprietary binary blob. A quick analysis shows that it was build with Linaro GCC 5.3-2016.02

```
> strings libpvrGBMWSEGL.so | grep GCC
GCC: (Linaro GCC 5.3-2016.02) 5.3.1 20160113
```

Meanwhile the library libgbm which dynamically calls it was build with Buildroot GCC 6.4.0

```
> strings libgbm.so | grep GCC
GCC: (Buildroot 2017.11-git-00884-g7af8140-dirty) 6.4.0
```

**Question:**

Should I expect these two library to be compatible in the manner in which I am using them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For many platforms, there is a published ABI document to which compilers are expected to adhere.  For C++ and on top of those platform ABIs, there is the [Itanium C++ ABI](https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/) (which has nothing to do with Itanium anymore and will be Itanium's lasting contribution to computing, I assume).

This does not extend to libraries, though.  There are many libcs for Linux, and something compiled and linked against glibc will not run on Bionic libc (Android) and vice versa, even if the architectures match.  Essentially the same thing is true for the C++ standard library (and even the implementation that comes with GCC comes with slightly different ABIs as option).

With ARM, there is also a considerable amount of sub-architecture variation.

The summary is: When everyone makes an effort, then what you are trying to do will work.  If not, probably not.  Getting this right for C++ is more difficult than for C.